# package.el asks whether I want to save modified files before package installation. How to disable this?

Tags: package

When I run `M-x package-install` to install a package, I get asked whether I want to save files, that have been modified since the last save (`Save file /a/b/c.txt? (y, n, !, ., q, C-r, d or C-h)` in the minibuffer). I get this prompt for each modified file, and, if installing multiple packages from the `*Packages*` buffer, I get asked multiple times! This is incredibly frustrating, especially as the files that I am asked about have nothing to do with compilation, and could, in fact, be any files at all, including ordinary text files.

I did a bit of sleuthing, and found that, at the end of the day, package.el runs `package-unpack` to install a package, which runs `package--compile`, which runs `byte-recompile-directory`. I have therefore set the following in my init.el (even though I don't think I should have to do that(!)):

`(setq compilation-ask-about-save nil)`

No improvement.

Frankly, I thought this must be a side-effect of some customization of mine, since in no way would I consider this to be desirable behavior...until I ran `emacs -Q` to reproduce this without my config, and, to my surprise, ran into the very same thing. While this seems baffling, it also offers me some hope that perhaps someone has figured out a way to disable this super-annoying prompt?

Comment: *Ask Emacs.* At the prompt, use `?` or `C-h` (as the prompt suggests), to learn what each of your options are. You will see that you can provide the same response for *all modified files in the package at once*. Do that and you will **not** be prompted for each modified file. (This does not respond to the part of your question that deals with prompts for multiple *packages*, however.)

Comment: I suggested filing this as a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the help text tells you when you type <kbd>C-h</kbd> (as prompted by `save-some-buffers`, which is the function responsible for the query), you can skip all remaining queries with a simple <kbd>RET</kbd> or <kbd>q</kbd>.

I certainly don't find myself in this situation so frequently that doing that is an onerous task, so this might be sufficient for you.

p.s. `compilation-ask-about-save` is related to running external compiler processes, and not to elisp byte-compilation.

**Edit:**

One option would be binding `noninteractive` ("Non-nil means Emacs is running without interactive terminal.") around `package--compile` with advice, as `byte-recompile-directory` won't trigger `save-some-buffers` in that case; but I think that's going to have some undesirable consequences further down.

Redefining `save-some-buffers` for the duration seems like a safer option:

```el
(defadvice package--compile (around no-byte-recompile-saves)
  "Inhibit `save-some-buffers' when byte-compiling packages."
  (require 'cl-lib)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'save-some-buffers) 'ignore))
    ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'package--compile)
```

Comment: Alas, this might help when installing a single package, but, if installing multiple packages (or a package with dependencies), I still get this prompt for each package being installed.

Comment: To explain why the above is a problem - I have a lot of packages installed. From time to time, I run an across-the-board upgrade with `U` in the `*Packages*` buffer. As you can imagine, this will have me pressing `q` like a maniac, as tens, if not hundreds of packages are being compiled. This also means that I cannot run the upgrade unattended and switch to some other task while it's going on, since I have to `q` away the prompts!

Comment: Excellent - the defadvice from your edit solves this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been suffering this as well: in long Emacs sessions
with multiple Tramp connections, I am prompted to save buffers
in remote machines when I grep my local sources.

Since Emacs 28 (currently, this is the master branch),
Emacs has added the value `save-some-buffers-root`
for the option `save-some-buffers-default-predicate`.

With this value, Emacs will prompt to save only those
modified buffers inside the current project.
For instance, at the Emacs sources, if you call
`save-some-buffers` from dir:

```
~/emacs_source/lisp
```

then, you'll be also prompted for a modified buffer at:

```
~/emacs_source/src
```

but you won't be prompted for a modified buffer at:

```
~/foodir
```

In case Emacs cannot find a project, then Emacs will
only ask for buffers whose `default-directory` is in a
subdir of the directory where `save-some-buffers` is invoked.

For example,

If you call it at:

```
~/foo/
```

you'll be prompted to save buffers at both:

```
~/foo/
~/foo/bar/
```

but you won't be prompted to save buffers at:

```
~/qux
```